# Can't get to refresh ListView automatically when deleting entries from SQLite base

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, refresh

I've been browsing StackOverflow for days now, looking for a solution to my problem, but all the similar questions that have been askes are WAY to complicated for me to understand!

So here it is: I have a ListView, that displays the elements in my SQLite database. For this, it uses a SimpleCursorAdapter. My code is NOT optimized, but I'm just a newbie.

Here's my code:

```
protected boolean onLongListItemClick(final View v, final int pos, long id) 
        {
           final String str=ReservationList.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
           Log.i("ListView", "onLongListItemClick string=" + str);
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FlightBook.this);
           builder.setMessage("Delete this entry from Flight Book?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
           {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
               {
                   Log.i("ID",""+pos);
                   rdb.removeReservationWithID((int)mAdapter.getItemId(pos));
                   **//NEED SOME CODE HERE TO REFRESH LISTVIEW AUTOMATICALLY**
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
           {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
               {
                   dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
           AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
           alert.show();
           return true;
        }
```

All I need and all I want is to know what should I put in the line I mentioned in the code to make the ListView be refreshed automatically. I tried a notifyDataChanged() on my adapter, but it just won't work (I know I should use threads and very complicated things such as ASyncTask, but too not explained correctly how to use them in this specific case).

Thank you for your aid and please, if you really want to help me, give me CODE, not links! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new cursor with the new data and load it into your adapter, like this:

```
myListAdapter.changeCursor(getCursor());
```

Comment: And how exactly, in the given code, do I "create a new cursor with the new data"? And where should I do that?

Comment: You just get a new cursor from your database, exactly like you did in your onCreate or whereever you first set a cursor for your ListView.

Comment: Done. Not working. If I got you right, here's what I should write:
`Cursor c = rdb.queueAll();
startManagingCursor(c);
mAdapter.changeCursor(c);`
instead of the line above. But it's not working, my list still dosen't refresh.

Comment: Is the method you are calling possibly working in a background thread? If so, you have to wait for that to finish.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, my bad! I commented the line that deletes the item from the base which is why I thought it wasn't working. :) 
It does work, actually, you rock, man!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) here.
The LoaderManager is a much more intelligent and generic implementation. [startManagingCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) is deprecated as well
An [Restart Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#restarting) call will refresh your view

Refer
[Properly Loading Data](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/)
[Understanding the LoaderManager](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html)

Comment: Whoa! Too complicated, sorry. :(

Comment: it depends. From my experience I prefer that. _My first thought about loader was the same. But now I understood how good it is_